# What does "~" mean in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Recently I've found these selectors:

```
i ~ i{
    width: 40%;
    }

i ~ i ~ i{
    width: 60%;
    }
```

Wonder what "~" stands for?

Comment: For better understand read this article. http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
E ~ F   an F element preceded by an E element
```

[More Info](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)

Answer (score 0):

E ~ F means an F element preceded by an E element

[CSS Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)